# Why doesn't this if statement work properly?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to remove the everything in an array I have that has more than 7 letters and less than 5.

The program runs but it doesn't remove the words that have more than 7 letters and less than 5 letters.

I have used an iterator to read the array, but it seems that it ignores the if statement

```
Iterator<String> it = muligeOrd.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    if(it.next().length()<=5 && it.next().length()>=7){
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `next` does?

Comment: Also, when will a string be shorter than 5 and longer than 7 simultaneously?

Comment: it should || instead

Comment: if it's not next what else? I think it takes the next word in the array

Comment: So you take the `next` word to check for `<=5` and then you take the `next` one after that to check for `>=7`. Is that what you want?

Comment: define "properly". also, `it.next()` read the doc for that. Also, your conditions don't really make sense.

Comment: the next should be fine, but your conditional is never going to return true. It is asking for two mutually exclusive conditions to be true at the same time

Comment: @SamSun Technically the OP is reading two different strings, and checking if the first one is <= 5 and the second one is >= 7.

Comment: @Anton It is not, the OP is checking the length of two different strings, one read by each `next()` call.

Comment: I can't believe nobody is catching on that the basic comparison condition can never be true.  _"more than 7 letters and less than 5"_ is impossible.

Comment: @azurefrog He's definitely not aware of that, though.

Comment: @JimGarrison OP already commented "*it should || instead*". It's the third comment. Now ask him why he didn't edit his question.

Comment: Oh yes, well that is just going to return random results. so there should be an assignment of it.next() before the checks

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula That's what post editing is for.  I have edited the post to match.  OP, if this is incorrect please revert the edit.

Comment: @JimGarrison that is one of the two bugs in the question, and answers explained that bug. Now the answers look strange because the question doesn't have that bug anymore. You could also fix the other bug in the question, so that nothing makes sense anymore.

Comment: If the OP says he intended to use OR in the question, then he should EDIT the post so it makes sense.  The other bug (calling `next()` twice) is the real bug. and that is covered in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, we have two MAJOR issues in one line

```
if(it.next().length()<=5 && it.next().length()>=7){
```

`.next()` will move the curser, since you are using a `&&`, if the length of the object is <= 5, the next call will move the curser to the next object in the collection; this is probably not what you want.

If this *is not* what you want, and you want to be chacking the same object, then how can its length be both >7 and <5 at the same time?

Try using this, move the curser once and get the object, then change `&&` to `||`, this will remove anything that is not exactly 6 characters in length.

```
String something = it.next();
if( something.length() <= 5 || something.length() >= 7 ) {
    it.remove();
}
```

In your post you also say

> The program runs but it doesn't remove the words that have more than 7 letters and less than 5 letters.

To me, this means that you want to keep everything that has 5, 6, or 7 characters; again if this is the case, you need to change the `<=`s to simply `<`.

```
String something = it.next();
if( something.length() < 5 || something.length() > 7 ) { 
    it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`it.next()` returns the next element and advances, so the second call after `&&` is on the next element.
Solution: put the element in a variable before the if statement, like so:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String str = it.next();
    if(str.length() <= 5 || str.length() >= 7) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Also it should be `||`, not `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code say "if the next element is 5 or less and the **element after that** is 7 or more, then ...". Don't call `next()` twice inside the loop.

Also, it you intended to check a single value, be aware that it cannot be **both** less than 5 and more than 7 at the same time. You likely meant `||`, not `&&`.

So, your code should be:

```
public void normalOrd() {
    for (Iterator<String> it = muligeOrd.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        String ord = it.next();
        if (ord.length() <= 5 || ord.length() >= 7) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your code so that you only call `it.next()` once per trip through the loop.

For example:

```
public void normalWord ( ) {

    Iterator<String> it = muligeOrd.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String nextWord = it.next();
        if ((nextWord.length() <= 5) || (nextWord.length() >= 7)) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```